# Automatically insert integer in cell when creating new row

Tags: excel, vba, static, insert, row

I have tried many methods to get this right but all of them (SEQUENCE, ROW(), Fill etc.) do not maintain history-I suspect I may need a little VBA to get this right. How do I check all the integers in a column and produce the next sequence when inserting a new row such that when the sheet is sorted the numbered sequences remain static? For example see below:

I have a table that contains an EMP_ID field, when I insert a new row it should check what values exist and insert the next sequential value (51) and remain static.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to get the highest number of a column, just use the `WorksheetFunction.Max` function.

Now all you have to do is to put this logic into the `Change`-Event of the Worksheet. Check if the entered data is part of the table (tables are called `ListObject` in VBA) and if the ID column of that row is empty. If yes, put the max ID + 1 into the ID column.

When you add data using Cut&Paste (so multiple values are entered at once), the change event is triggered only once, so I added a loop to process all modified cells.

Put the following code into the *Worksheet* module of the sheet that contains the table. I assume that the sheet contains only one table and that the ID-column is column 7 (your image is hard to read), maybe you have to adapt the code to your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const IDCol = 7

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Target
        If Not Intersect(Me.ListObjects(1).Range, cell) Is Nothing Then    ' Cell is part of the table
            If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) And cell.Column <> IDCol And IsEmpty(Me.Cells(cell.row, IDCol)) Then
                Dim maxID As Long
                maxID = WorksheetFunction.Max(Me.Columns(IDCol).EntireColumn)
                Me.Cells(cell.row, IDCol) = maxID + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Row insertion *is* triggering the change event. With my code, the number is generated once data is filled into any of the new cells. If it should be added immediately, just remove the `Not IsEmpty(cell.Value)`-part of the If-statement.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't think he only likes inserting a blank row... I will delete my comment and vote up the answer. :)

Comment: Your explanation and the solution is top-class, thank you. Not sure how to mark this as the correct answer, but this is it.

Comment: @Minyun: There should be a gray checkmark at the left top of the answer. Click on it to make it "green" (accept the answer)